# Which MF Play sample code shows proper COM techniques in Media Foundation?

Tags: windows, video, com, atl, ms-media-foundation

I’m now crawling up the steep learning curve of Windows Media Foundation and I’m focusing on two very similar code samples to help me understand the technology. Even though both use Media Session for a very simple “Play” program that plays video from a file, there are important subtle differences.

The first sample is Microsoft’s MF Play located at:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd979592(v=vs.85).aspx

It does not initialize COM and does not perform any critical section locks yet it plays video very well. Will the lack of using COM restrict it’s use in other ways such as when processing multiple video streams to separate windows by multithreading? Since this code is online, I may be naively assuming this code is more current.

The second sample is from the book “Developing Microsoft Media Foundation Applications - By Anton Polinger”. I downloaded sample code from here:
https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/content/images/9780735656598/downloads/9780735656598_files.zip

This Play program in the Chapter 3 folder is slightly more complex due to the use of these COM initialization functions:

```
// initialize COM
hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
...
// uninitialize COM
CoUninitialize();
```

It also uses several critical section locks using:

```
CComCritSecLock<CComAutoCriticalSection> lock(m_critSec);
```

But mysteriously there are no corresponding unlocks(). So can someone please explain these potential important differences between these two code samples and which ones I should use? I’m concerned that if I don’t use the COM methods I may have problems later when I attempt to stream multiple videos to multiple windows, or worse I could have reliability problems.

On a side note, the Polinger code works but does not handle window resizing while playing video. I attempted to add in the code similar to the way the MS code does by using this code after a window resizing event:

```
m_pVideoDisplay->SetVideoPosition(NULL, &rcDest)
```

Using this just caused the program to freeze.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About "It does not initialize COM" - you have seen not all code of it - research [Media Session Playback Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728900(v=vs.85).aspx) - you will find call `MFStartup` in player.cpp - it is enough for MediaFoundation (MF). I have read book of Polinger and in the code it calls some COM thread model sensitive function - for example, DirectX. But, from my experience it looks like that MF calls CoInitialize from context of `MFStartup` calling. More over, in code from book of Polinger there is call Apartment thread model: `hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);`, but MF supports execution from Multithreaded model - it does not sensitive for it.

About "But mysteriously there are no corresponding unlocks()." - `CComCritSecLock` is object oriented wrapper for section lock and `unlocks()` is called in destructor of `CComCritSecLock` - `~CComCritSecLock()`.

About resizing - `m_pVideoDisplay->SetVideoPosition(NULL, &rcDest)` - it looks like that `rcDest` has wrong value - according to 
[IMFVideoDisplayControl::SetVideoPosition method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms697352(v=vs.85).aspx)

`The destination rectangle defines a rectangle within the clipping window where the video appears. It is specified in pixels, relative to the client area of the window. To fill the entire window, set the destination rectangle to {0, 0, width, height},`

I can advise research my project on `CodeProject` site: [NativeMediaFoundationPlayer:](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1017223/CaptureManager-SDK#fourtyfirstdemoprogram) and [WPFMediaFoundationPlayer](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1017223/CaptureManager-SDK#fourtyseconddemoprogram)

Regards,
Evgeny Pereguda

Comment: Thank you for your response and links! And especially for clearing up how the destructor does the unlock. Not such a mystery now.

Answer (score 1):

The sample inaccurately omits COM initialization and this is incorrect. It should have called CoInitialize[Ex] the usual way. You can check Windows SDK 7.x samples for Media Foundation and the samples show proper initialization. For example, [this](https://github.com/ermilindwalekar/Windows_Classic_Samples/blob/cded84bed49cb8ef2095e6470ac83ee3264c4113/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/mediafoundation/Transcode/main.cpp#L34) is how `Transcode` sample does it.

As Evgeny mentioned, [`CComCritSecLock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33ydddb1.aspx) and `CComAutoCriticalSection` are well known and documented ATL classes which help you with automatic unlocking of critical sections.

> Use this class to lock and **unlock** objects in a safer way than with the `CComCriticalSection` Class or `CComAutoCriticalSection` Class.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I did not research MFPlayer2 since it uses the deprecated IMFPMediaPlayer API but I will look at it to see how it uses the COM locking techniques.

Comment: Even though MFPlayer2 might be using deprecated (bad example, that is), COM rules apply the same way though.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who may be working the the Polinger code example I referred to in my OP, I was able to successfully add window resizing to the Polinger example by doing this:

In the winmain.cpp file, WndProc callback function, I added:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
...
    case WM_SIZE:
        OnResize(LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));
        break;
```

Then added this function to the winmain.cpp file:

```
//  Handler for WM_SIZE messages.
void OnResize(WORD width, WORD height)
{
    if (g_pPlayer)
    {
        g_pPlayer->ResizeVideo(width, height);
    }
}
```

Then added this function to the Player.cpp file:

```
HRESULT CPlayer::ResizeVideo(WORD width, WORD height)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    CComCritSecLock<CComAutoCriticalSection> lock(m_critSec);

    if (m_pVideoDisplay)
    {
        // Set the destination rectangle.
        RECT rcDest = { 0, 0, width, height };
        hr = m_pVideoDisplay->SetVideoPosition(NULL, &rcDest);
    }

    return hr;
}
```